# Google App Script, .getValue returns ERROR

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, getvalue

I have quite a big problem. If I read columns cells with for loop and range(r,c.).getValue() (same for reading with range(r,c,m,1).getValues() ) the values are not read. I got #ERROR!. I am reading cell values that are some as reference from other sheet and other with some if, round and plus/minus calculations.

[image: DataSource]

As you maybe see on the figure I have a fixed test value over some columns (number 2, 3, 4, 5) and these are always read OK.

[image: ErrorCodes]
[image: SourceCode]

In the source code I added 3 lines that read fixed entered values (2,3,4,5).

Any suggestion why as I have several scripts with reading cell values but nothing similar happend till now.

Thank you!

Comment: Are they `=googlefinance()` or `=import*()` cells?

Comment: Could you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, free of sensitive information?

Answer (score 0):

Regards,

If my understanding if correct, you would like to obtain values from cells that have dynamic values (calculated or referenced).

It might fail if you use `range.getValue()` since there are no actual value in the cell. You can try to use `range.getDisplayValues()` instead to get the displayed value. This is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue).

If you are doing this, your code will be like this :

```
for(var ii=0; ii < iDNRows; ii++)
{
   i0mik_od_zacetka = sIzracuni.getRange(ii+StartRowData, iStartColumnData).getDisplayValue();
   .
   .
   .
   
}
```

Or you can do `.getDisplayValues()` :

```
values = sIzracuni.getRange(startrow,startcol,rownum,colnum).getDisplayValues();
```

Do comment if I have misunderstood your question.